# Mouseover section background according to the title

Tags: php, html, background, background-image

I was trying to make the background a bit more interactive in this section, whereby the background of the section will change accordingly to the title. What I am trying to do at my code, was to have a container that contain the background-image, and when I hover over to different title, it will change to its assigned background-image.

Not sure what I have done incorrectly. I did try to have images to be replaced by the hovering another image element before, but not with span text. Please advice.

HTML/CSS :

```css
.expertise_menu {
  *background-image: url('../ga7-theme/img/expertise/Expertise_1.png');
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 999;
}
.design-consultancy span:hover img {
  *background-image: url('../ga7-theme/img/expertise/Expertise_1.png');
  display: block;
  *opacity: 1;
  z-index: 999;
}
.expertise_menu .turnkey-project span:hover {
  background-image: url('../ga7-theme/img/expertise/Expertise_2.png');
  opacity: 1;
}
.expertise_menu .inhouse-production span:hover {
  background-image: url('../ga7-theme/img/expertise/Expertise_3.png');
  opacity: 1;
}
.expertise_menu .event-management span:hover {
  background-image: url('../ga7-theme/img/expertise/Expertise_4.png');
  opacity: 1;
}
.expertise_menu #visual-merchandising span:hover {
  background-image: url('../ga7-theme/img/expertise/Expertise_5.png');
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section id="expertise" class="fullscreen specific-padding-4">
  <div class="content-a">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="container col-lg-4">
        <h2 style="text-align:right;">EXPERTISE</h2>
      </div>
      <!-- col-lg-12  -->
    </div>
    <!-- row  -->

    <!-- BACKGROUND -->
    <div class="fullscreen design-consultancy"></div>
    <div class="fullscreen turnkey-project"></div>
    <div class="fullscreen inhouse-production"></div>
    <div class="fullscreen event-management"></div>
    <div class="fullscreen visual-merchandising"></div>

    <div class="content-b col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
      <div class="expertise_menu">
        <span class="design-consultancy">Design Consultancy</span>
        <br>
        <span class="turnkey-project">Turn Key Project</span>
        <br>
        <span class="inhouse-production">In-House Productions</span>
        <br>
        <span class="event-management">Event Management</span>
        <br>
        <span class="visual-merchandising">Visual Merchandising</span>
        <br>
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- col-lg-12  -->

    <div class="container-fluid col-lg-8">
      <!-- E/M/P/T/Y/ -->
    </div>
    <!-- col-lg-12  -->
  </div>
  <!-- row  -->
</section>
<!-- container  -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all your background divs and keep **one single div** and give it an ID. I will use "dynamic_background" as an example.

```
<div id="dynamic_background" class="fullscreen"></div>
```

Add an ID to your expertise menu such as "expertise_items"

```
<div id="expertise_items" class="expertise_menu">
```

**Using jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $("#expertise_items span").hover(function() {
    var background = $(this).attr("class");
    $("#dynamic_background").attr("class", background);
  });
});
```

**CSS**
Update your css to just render the background image as part of that class and make sure you specify the height and width of the container as the size you want your image or if you want it to be responsive you can do that as well.

```
#dynamic_background.turnkey-project {
    background-image: url('../ga7-theme/img/expertise/Expertise_1.png');
}
```

Here is an example fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/adrianopolis/euc7p9qg/

Comment: So my CSS should look something like:

Comment: So my CSS should look something like this?: 

#expertise_items .design-consultancy span:hover > #dynamic_background {
 background-image: url('../ga7-theme/img/expertise/Expertise_1.png');
}

Comment: What the script is doing basically is taking your class attribute from the spans in your menu which you have assigned image backgrounds to in your stylesheet. It than takes that class name and adds it to your fullscreen background container.